# android deplayed notification, working immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

Below is my code used inside and onClickListner, i want to show the notification, some time later say 30 sec, but it is shown immediately.

```
        String title = "sample title"
        String text = "sample text";

        Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();
        target.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, model.getAlarmHour() );
        target.set( Calendar.MINUTE, model.getAlarmMinute() );
        target.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );

        int icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error;

        String ns = context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( context, WakeUpNotify.class );
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, target.getTimeInMillis() );
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(appContext, title, text, contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify( notifyId, notification );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `target` does not control *when* the `Notification` is displayed. It merely determines what time is shown in the notification drawer entry for this item.